# PHP dropdown list processing

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to process a form with a dropdown list and my PHP handler script is returning 'null' instead of values selected. The first option to select in most cases is "none" and others have times like 7.00 am or 7.30 am. Why does the script return an array with 'null' in place of times selected by the user?

How do I fix that?

```css
body,p, form {
 font-family: "sans-serif", sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 background-color: #F5D63E; 
}

form li{
 list-style: none;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
form ul, p {
 padding-left: 40px;
 color: #291400;
}
label {
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 10px;
 
}
textarea {
 width: 700px;
 height: 90px;
}
dt {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
select {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-right: 30px;
}
form li textarea {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1b.css">
<title>Database of Mass times3</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<p> Please enter Mass times for your local parish or a church that you attend regularly. 
    Be sure to include any other <br> relevant information and to click 'submit' at the bottom.  </p>
 
 <form action="action_handler.php" method="POST"> 
   <ul>
  <li>
   <label for "parish"> <b>Parish</b></label> 
   <input type="text" name= "parish" value="">
  </li>
  <li>
   <label for "town"> <b>City/Town</b></label> 
   <input type="text" name= "town" value="">
  </li>
  
  <li>
   <dt><b>Monday - Friday:</b> 
   <div id=Mass1>
   <label for "MassTime1"> First Mass</label> 
   <select name="masstime1">
   <option value="Null">None</option>
   <option value="6.00 am"> 6.00 am</option>
   <option value="6.15">6.15 am</option>
   <option value="6.30">6.30 am</option>
   <option value="6.45">6.45 am</option>
   <option value="7.00">7.00 am</option>
   </select>
   <label for "language"> Language</label> 
   <input type="text" name="language1">
   </div>
   <div id=Mass2>
   <label for "MassTime2"> Second Mass</label> 
   <select name="masstime2">
   <option value="null" selected>None </option>
   <option value="6.30" selected>6.30 am</option>
   <option value="6.45" selected>6.45 am</option>
   <option value="7.00">7.00 am</option>
   <option value="7.15">7.15 am</option>
   <option value="7.30">7.30 am</option>
   <option value="12.30">12.30 pm</option>
   <option value="1.00">1.00 pm</option>
   <option value="1.30">1.30 pm</option>
   </select>
   <label for "language"> Language</label> 
   <input type="text" name="language2">
   </div>
   <div id=Mass3>
   <label for "MassTime3"> Third Mass</label> 
   <select name="masstime3">
   <option value="null">None </option>
   <option value="12.30">12.30 pm</option>
   <option value="1.00">1.00 pm</option>
   <option value="1.30">1.30 pm</option>
   <option value="5.00">5.00 pm</option>
   <option value="5.15">5.15 pm</option>
   <option value="5.30">5.30 pm</option>
   <option value="5.45">5.45 pm</option>
   <option value="6.00">6.00 pm</option>
   </select>
   <label for "language"> Language</label> 
   <input type="text" name="language">
   </div>
        </li>
  <li>
   <label for "Comments"> Other relevant information </label> 
   <textarea id="Comments" name="Comments"></textarea>
  </li>
  <li>
   <label for "email"> Your e-mail address</label> 
   <input type="text" name= "address" value="">
  </li>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </ul>
 
 </form>
 <p> Thank you!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We're going to have to see the "action_handler.php" code you wrote so we can see how you are processing stuff... Also, the CSS isn't really necessary.

Comment: you need to post your php code. maybe you're not using $_POST['var'] to get your data?

Comment: My handler script looks like this


<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Action Handler</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <pre>
 <?php 
 
 print_r($_POST); 
 echo "<p>Thanks for providing this data.</p>";
 echo "<p>We will contact you in case we need any clarification.</p>";
 ?>
 </pre>
 
 </body>
</html>

Comment: And the handler script returns this:
Array
(
    [parish] => Newberry
    [town] => Markham
    [masstime1] => null
    [language1] => English
    [masstime2] => null
    [language2] => English
    [masstime3] => null
    [language] => 
    [masstime1s] => null
    [masstime2s] => null
    [antmasstime] => null
    [masstime4] => null
    [masstime5] => 5.00
    [Comments] => None.
    [address] => john@gmail.com
)
Thanks for providing this data.

We will contact you in case we need any clarification.

Comment: @CharlesM.Sendegeya I just tested, and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: Why "selected" is there 3 times (masstime2)? I think there can only be 1 default option.

Comment: <selected> shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Mark: Oh, so what could be the problem on my end (I'm running WAMP server on my computer, BTW)?

Comment: @CharlesM.Sendegeya What was the problem?